# Ando dots or holes in concrete walls

Tags: structural-engineering, concrete

I am making a concrete poured wall with holes where the bars to support the wood frame remain. Question is with plywood supporting frame what is the greatest distance between bars that will still support the wall so it doesn’t distort. My builder is saying 2 feet max but I see walls with much larger blocks with these holes

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.